# Is conceptually wrong to use SQL with Node.JS?

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am starting to learn Node.JS and being an old school developer I grew up surrounded by SQL.

Now I have read that NoSQL (specifically MongoDB) is the perfect companion for Node.JS and so I was asking myself if use Node.JS with relational databases may be considered conceptually wrong.

Or better asking, I HAVE to use NoSQL database with Node.JS or it will depend on the characteristics of the application, meaning that I can freely choose between SQL and NoSQL depending on what will be better for my **project**?

*The point is that I have a small desktop project about to start with and it would be the perfect chance to practice Node.JS but since it's a project that is going to be actually used by someone I wouldn't like to figure a bit further that it was a wrong choice. The project in question is based on simple tables containing customers, products and orders. Opinions?*

Comment: The choice between SQL or NoSQL is based on the requirements of the application, load, tolerance to non-synchronized, stale data, etc. Both technologies share similarities but also fundamental differences in how the store and treat the data.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using relational databases with JavaScript. It is more important to ask yourself how you want your data to be structured and how are you planning to query it. And then there is of course ACID compliance which NoSQL usually doesn't offer.

Comment: Your tables sound like the standard pedagogical case of relational data. There is an ORM for node called Sequelize which you may find useful.